# C++ - size of SP_DEVINFO_LIST_DETAIL_DATA_W on 64 bit

Tags: c++, data-structures, msdn

On 64 bit, the size of [SP_DEVINFO_LIST_DETAIL_DATA_W](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is 560. Shouldn't it be 554?

```
typedef struct _SP_DEVINFO_LIST_DETAIL_DATA_W {
  DWORD  cbSize;
  GUID   ClassGuid;
  HANDLE RemoteMachineHandle;
  WCHAR  RemoteMachineName[SP_MAX_MACHINENAME_LENGTH];
} SP_DEVINFO_LIST_DETAIL_DATA, *PSP_DEVINFO_LIST_DETAIL_DATA;
```

cbSize is 4, ClassGuid is 16, RemoteMachineHandle is 8 (64 bit), RemoteMachineName is 2*(260+3) (SP_MAX_MACHINENAME_LENGTH is MAX_PATH + 3)

So, 4+16+8+2*263=554. Why does sizeof(_SP_DEVINFO_LIST_DETAIL_DATA_W) return 560 ?

Comment: Padding. The compiler is allowed to add arbitrary free space between members for speed reasons.

Comment: The same size is returned outside the compiler, i.e. when calling WinAPI functions through shared libraries.

Comment: Why do people always think they know this? And refuse to search about it? It's asked almost daily :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overlooking the requirement to align the fields, important to ensure they can be accessed efficiently by the processor.  The HANDLE type is 64-bits, 8 bytes, when you target x64.  The RemoteMachineHandle member is therefore aligned to an offset that is a multiple of 8.  Which moves it from offset 20 to offset 24, the next offset that is divisible by 8.  The extra 4 bytes are *padding* and are unused.

Which makes the structure size 4 + 16 + 4 + 8 + 2*263 = 558 bytes.

There's an additional problem - an array of this struct would make the handle again misaligned.  The element at index 1 would have the Handle at offset 558 + 4 + 16 + 4 = 582.  Which is not a multiple of 8, the member will be misaligned again.

So the compiler adds an *additional* 2 bytes of padding to the end of the struct so the total size of the struct is a multiple of 8.  Thus:

```
Offset  Size    Member
   0      4     cbSize
   4     16     ClassGuid
  20      4     -
  24      8     RemoteMachineHandle
  32    526     RemoteMachineName
 558      2     -
-------------
        560
```

Comment: You are right about alignment padding being used, but are you sure the padding is added after `ClassGuid` and not after `cbSize`?, That would align `ClassGuid` to an 8-byte offset, without affecting the alignment of the remaining members.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, you can check it with the offsetof() macro.  A GUID is a structure under the hood, it largest member type is Data1, a *long* and therefore only has an alignment requirement of 4.

Comment: A `GUID` is explicitly byte-aligned to ensure its 16-byte size by forcing no padding between its members in all environments. That does not effect alignment when using `GUID` values in other structs.

Comment: No, it aligns to 4.  Just try this yourself with a struct with a char and a GUID and the offsetof() macro.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing padding to accomodate the alignment requirement of some member. I am not familiar with these types so I can't explain the alignment of this structure, however.

If you really want to pack your struct in the most efficient way, you can order the members by size (decreasing). The compiler isn't normally allowed to reorder the members.

Answer (score 0):

I try to work with SetupDiGetDeviceInfoListDetail and got wrong size too. finally I found the solution

this is the definition of the struct

```
typedef struct _SP_DEVINFO_LIST_DETAIL_DATA {
  DWORD  cbSize;
  GUID   ClassGuid;
  HANDLE RemoteMachineHandle;
  TCHAR  RemoteMachineName[SP_MAX_MACHINENAME_LENGTH];
} SP_DEVINFO_LIST_DETAIL_DATA, *PSP_DEVINFO_LIST_DETAIL_DATA;
```

in setupapi.h

```
#define SP_MAX_MACHINENAME_LENGTH   (MAX_PATH + 3)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc249520.aspx

```
MAX_PATH 0x00000104
```

There for

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct  SP_DEVINFO_LIST_DETAIL_DATA
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public Guid classGuid;
        public int RemoteMachineHandle;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 263)]public string RemoteMachineName;

    };
```